# Is it possible to have SAML 2.0 Authentication and JWT Authentication in a single Application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, saml-2.0

Our application currently has its own authentication process using JWT.

We want to add a SSO(Single Sign-on) login only for a specific role of users in our application using SAML 2.0 (Azure AD).

Is it possible to have 2 separate authentication protocols in the same Spring-Boot application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

The idea is that you can register many `AuthenticationProvider` where each `AuthenticationProvider` is responsible for a particular type of authentication mechanism (i.e. One for JWT , one for Azure AD in you cases).

Spring Security will then loop through these `AuthenticationProvider` one by one to check which one can successfully authenticate the request. It will stop looping once it finds an `AuthenticationProvider` can successfully authenticate.

That means in each of your `AuthenticationProvider`,  you can get the role info for the current requested user and then check if he has the required roles for that authentication mechanism . Simply throw `AuthenticationException` if he does not has the required roles.

Comment: Thank you for this confirmation! I now have to search for AuthenticationProvider and how to implement it in our system.

Comment: @NekoTamago. You are welcomed and good luck to your journey :D